# Как в Ispmanager сделать разные версии PHP CLI для разных пользователей?

Tags: php, ispmanager, консоль

Вызывать через `/opt/php71/bin/php` как то слишком долго и запоминать тяжело.

На одной машинке висят разные сайты. *Php от 5.5 до 7.1*.
Версия `Ispmanager 5 Lite. Ubuntu Server 16.04 LTS`.

В основном, интересует версия 7.1. Пробовал прописать:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/php php /opt/php71/bin/php 10  
update-alternatives --set php /opt/php71/bin/php
```

Вместе с версией, меняется нативная версия с 7.0 на 7.1, что вводит меня в ступор. Скрин подкрепил ниже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]